# I cant find whats causing my program to stop working after i but everything into separate functions

Tags: python

So I originally had everything outside functions. Meaning there was no 'def' or 'return' anywhere. and all the displays came out fine.

But now that I'm trying to use Main function as a switch to call other functions. my output disappeared, and when i entered '1' then '1' would just be repeated back at me. I am confused how where I made my mistake.

Then I am trying to return to my main function after I enter 'a' but I do not know how to do that.

Can anyone help me fix this?

~Im using Thonny Python IDE on a raspberry pi if that helps.

Here is my code:

## #

```
import sys, random

def main():
    slct= input()
    if slct==1:
        set1()
    elif slct==2:
        set2()
    elif slct ==3:
        set3()
    return

def set1():
    n1= random.randint(0,9)
    pw1= random.randint(1,3)

    print(n1)
    if pw1==1:
        print('one')
    elif pw1:
        print('ten')
    else:
        print('hundred')
    return

def set2():
    n2= random.randint(0,9)
    pw2= random.randint(1,3)

    print(n2)
    if pw2==1:
        print('thousand')
    elif pw2:
        print('ten thousand')
    else:
        print('hundred thousand')
    return

def set3():
    n3= random.randint(0,9)
    pw3= random.randint(1,3)

    print(n3)
    if pw3==1:
        print('one million')
    elif pw3:
        print('ten million')
    else:
        print('hundred million')
    return
```

Comment: You never called `main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need call main().

add `main()` at the end of your file.

Also you don't need to add `return` at the end of every function unless you want to return any value e.g. `return "passed"`

I don't know what you are doing with this code but as set1(), set2() and set3() are same,following code is also similar to what you have:

```
import sys, random

def main():
    n1= random.randint(0,9)
    pw1= random.randint(1,3)

    print(n1)
    if pw1==1:
        print('one')
    elif pw1:
        print('ten')
    else:
        print('hundred')
    return

main()
```

Comment: Or maybe use `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` so that the script can be imported.

Comment: The words for each set change. For instance set1() does 'one', 'ten' and 'hundred', while set2() does 'thousand', 'ten thousand' and 'hundred thousand'. Which is why i'm trying to do different functions. I realize I didn't write the words correctly (fixed wording now).

Comment: oh turns out I need to have made slct into an integer to compare it. so i just inserted slct=int(slct) after the input() line